# HEX & Decimal conversion

Tags: decimal, hex

I have a binary file , the definition of its content is as below : ( all data is stored
in little endian (ie. least significant byte first)) . The example numbers  below are HEX

```
11 63 39 46             --- Time, UTC in seconds since 1 Jan 1970.
01 00                   --- 0001 = No Fix, 0002 = SPS
97 85 ff e0 7b db 4c 40 --- Latitude, as double
a1 d5 ce 56 8d 26 28 40 --- Longitude, as double
f0 37 e1 42             --- Height in meters, as float
fe 2b f0 3a             --- Speed in km/h, as float
00 00 00 00             --- Heading (degrees ?), as float
01 00                   --- RCR, log reason. 0001=Time, 0004=Distance
59 20 6a f3 4a 26 e3 3f --- Distance in meters, as double,
2a                      --- ? Don't know
a8                      --- Checksum, xor of all bytes above not including 0x2a
```

the data from the Binary file "in HEX" is as below

```
"F25D39460200269652F5032445401F4228D79BCC54C09A3A2743B4ADE73F2A83"
```

I appreciate if you can support me to translate this data line based on the instruction before.

Comment: Despite the bad formatting of the instructions the content seems quite clear (except of course second-last byte). What is your specific problem with the description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably wrong, but here's a shot at it using Ruby:

```
hex   = "F25D39460200269652F5032445401F4228D79BCC54C09A3A2743B4ADE73F2A83"
ints  = hex.scan(/../).map{ |s| s.to_i(16) }
raw   = ints.pack('C*')
fields = raw.unpack( 'VvEEVVVvE')

p fields
#=> [1178164722, 2, 42.2813707974677, -83.1970117467067, 1126644378, 1072147892, nil, 33578, nil]

p Time.at( fields.first )
#=> 2007-05-02 21:58:42 -0600
```

I'd appreciate it if someone well-versed in [`#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002222) and [`#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000760) would show me a better way to accomplish the first three lines.

Comment: I am not sure about the other values , but I am sure that the time is correct , . How did you do it. are there any code in vb.net or C# to understand . thank you all for your support .

Comment: @waleednosir 1. Convert each hex character pair to the integer value. 2. Create a raw byte array from all those integers, treating each as an unsigned byte. 3. Extract the first four bytes (`V`) as an unsigned little-endian long. 4. Treat those as the epoch.

Comment: Thanks so much , it works . Thanks again .  But I do not understand how did you convert the integer value 1178164722  to time and date .  Also , why was the you have read the first HEX value in reverse  to convert it to INTeger . I mean that the value 1178164722 is the decimal value of  46395DF2 while the first 4 bytes of my code were the reverse ie F25D3946 . Please note that your results are OK but i do not understand why. also , are there any simple code in VB.net or C# that does this nice things. . you have solved it in 3 lines of code only . that is really amazing .

Comment: @waleednosir Conversion from epoch to time object is part of the `Time` class in Ruby (or the `Date` in JavaScript, with milliseconds). The little-endian decoding causes the bytes to be read in reverse order. I'm sorry, I don't know either VB.net or C# to be able to tell you how to accomplish the same task in those languages. Perhaps you should try a Google search such as `"decoding byte streams little endian C#"`

Comment: Thanks Phrogs for your clarification . I really appreciate this so much .

Comment: @waleednosir Perhaps you could vote up (or accept) the answer if you feel it has been helpful.

Comment: sorry for delay , I did not relealse that there is Accept or reject pathway of each question . It is my fault . I have accepted your genius answers and inspiration .Sorry for delay

Answer (score 0):

My [Cygnus Hex Editor](http://www.softcircuits.com/cygnus/) could load such a file and, using structure templates, display the data in its native formats.

Beyond that, it's just a matter of doing through each value and working out the translation for each byte.

Comment: sorry for delay , I did not relealse that there is Accept or reject pathway of each question . It is my fault . I have  accepted your genius answers and inspiration .Sorry for delay